# can't import an installed package c# in visual studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keras, package

(Sorry for my bad english)
I am working on a unity 2019 project and I created a model.h5 file with keras in python and I want to load this model in visual stusio C# with Kera.NET package

I installed Keras.NET successfully

[installed Keras.NET package.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3PS6.png)

but I got this error when I tried to import it in my code
[using Keras error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSJPG.png)

> Gravité   Code    Description Projet  Fichier Ligne   État de la suppression
> Erreur    CS0246  Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'Keras' est
> introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une référence
> d'assembly ?) Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\asus\Documents\Unity 2019
> Projects\Kinect test\Assets\Scripts\Keras_Test.cs 2   Actif

it means Keras is not recognized

thanks for help

Comment: right-click on your .csproj file and click Manage NuGet Packages. Look at your installed packages, does your project have Keras.NET installed?

Comment: I don't have "Manage NuGet Packages" when I do right-click on Assembly-CSharp.csproj , I clicked on Tools - Nuget Pacakge Manager - Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions and I saw Keras.NET is installed in all files.csproj , I don't understand why Keras is not recognized when I import it in code

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed the problem

in my version of Visual Studio 2019 I didn't find 'Add reference when I did right-click on "Assembly-CSharp.csproj\Reference"
I did right-click on Project Tab then 'Add reference'